# How to store small computer equipment in a home context?

Tags: storage, cabling, cable-management

I have a small network at home and with time more and more small equipment was added (such as the Internet box, a RPi, powered hub, external USB drive, etc.).

Right now all of this is pretty much stacked with cables flourishing behind. I was wondering if there are simple, low cost solutions to store such equipment (in the context of an apartment, ideally in a slot between the furniture).

Right now my idea is to take a grid similar to that

[image]

and strap equipment to it. The intended usage for the grid is not that one, strapping can be tricky, etc. I hope there is a solution which is more adapted to computer equipment (but not the racks you find in data centers or computer closets, this is really in the context on an apartment and small equipment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structured media enclosures are a common solution.

[image: Structured Media Enclosure]

It's basically a cabinet that can be built into a wall, where all the devices can be stored. It usually has some form of cable management, and a way to affix devices.

Comment: I was thinking about that but it is not that evident to use in an apartment (if I had a house that would have been the solution). I was looking for something more streamlined (like I mentioned: ideally it would fit between furniture)

Comment: @WoJ you could use a structured media enclosure, and build a frame around it, and make a table out of it.  You're only limited by your imagination, and carpentry skills.  You might even be able to find a small end table, of which you could attach an enclosure between the legs. I'm not sure if the exact product you're looking for exists.

Comment: @WoJ How about an old tv stand that has shelves with a glass door?